# how to get position of bitmap inside canvas?

Tags: android

i have a canvas and an image inside canvas.i need know the position of the bitmap inside the canvas.
in my case x and y are not static values.how to hide this image while touch on it?
what is the advantage of using SurfaceView over View.Here i am using view.

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Bitmap imgtable = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.table_01);
    int x=50;
    int y=50;
    canvas.drawBitmap(imgtable, x, y, null);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hold on to the values x and y as long as you need to.

So for example of you could declared x and y at the class level change them when you need to and then get their value when you need to to.

Comment: but i have 36 imgtable.i need to move the positions of each image.any other method?  `thank you`